# Is there a way to shuffle dataset using cross_validate in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn cross_validate to get train_score and test_scores.

is there a way to shuffle dataset when splitting dataset? right now is it being split in order of rows? so if there are 100 rows of data, first 1~10 will be hold-out set, next 11~20 and so on?

here is my code:

```
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
scores = cross_val_score(estimator=gbr_onehot,
                        X=X,
                        y=y,
                        cv=kfold,
                        scoring="neg_mean_squared_error",
                        n_jobs=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set `random_state` to `None`, it will randomly split the dataset when calling `get_n_splits(X)` or using it in CV

You have `random_state = 0` which effectively fixes the random shuffling of your data

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to shuffle dataset when splitting dataset? right now is it being split in order of rows?

Based on the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html), you already decided if it is shuffled before or not:

the command:

> shuffleboolean, optional
>
> ```
> Whether to shuffle the data before splitting into batches.
> ```

decides about if if you shuffle the data before or not, and you setted it to: `shuffle=True` that means the rows are already shuffled.

The other command:

> random_stateint, RandomState instance or None, optional, default=None
>
> ```
> If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number generator; If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number generator; If None, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used by np.random. Only used when shuffle is True. This should be left to None if shuffle is False.
> ```

Will make your shuffle repiclatable, that means if you set it to a random_state number you will always generate the same shuffle.